# XML Parsing in Java having user defined elements

Tags: java, xml, tree, treemap

I have huge number of XML files for which parsing needs to be done and generate a tree structure and further read to move data into database.
Following is the structure which i think suffices my requirement. TreeNode class will have tag name, its properties and its parent tag (Tags here are xml elements)

```
public class TreeNode {

    String tagname;
    Map<String, String> tagmap;
    TreeNode parent;
    List<TreeNode> children;

    public TreeNode(String tagname, Map<String, String> tagmap) {

        this.tagname = tagname;
        this.tagmap = tagmap;
        this.children = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    }


    public TreeNode addChild(String tagname,Map<String, String> tagmap) {
        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(tagname,tagmap);
        childNode.parent = this;
        this.children.add(childNode);
        return childNode;
    }
```

Now I am finding it difficult to parse XML file. Sample XML file is below

```
<head>
    <link href="files/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<div class="toolbar" style="display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%">
    <TABLE datatable="0" summary="">                
        <prj:if condition="Platform">
           <tr>
              <td nowrap><prj:toolbar name="First RunningTest"><prj:running property="HTML"/></prj:toolbar></td>    
               <td>&nbsp;</td>  
         </tr>

         <tr>       
              <td nowrap><prj:toolbar name="Second RunningTest"><prj:running property="HTML"/></prj:toolbar>    
               <td>&nbsp;</td>  
         </tr>

         <tr>   
               <td nowrap><prj:toolbar name="Third RunningTest"><prj:running property="HTML"/></prj:toolbar>    
               <td>&nbsp;</td>  
         </tr>
        </prj:if>

        </TABLE>
</div>
```

Apart from HTML tags, prj tags are there project specific.

So the tree structure would be

```
root     
--head (its map will be empty)    
    --link  (its map will all its properties i.e. key,value pair)

--div    
    --table
       --prj_if
         --tr    
            --td     
                 --prj_toolbar
                     --prj_running 
            --td
         --tr    
            --td 
                 --prj_toolbar    
                     --prj_running
            --td
         --tr    
            --td     
                 --prj_toolbar
                     --prj_running
            --td
```

XML can contain any element(there could be hundreds of more prj tags apart from HTML tags). So i need to store all tags,its prop/value pair and its child node details. How do i read XML and move into Treemap. Also, once populated how to traverse the treemap to read its maps and its child elements map data.
please help in parsing XML

Comment: What infrastructure are you using to parse the XML? Have you looked into JAXB at all?

Comment: @Ryan J ,I have not worked on JAXB. As I am reading,In all basic examples of Unmarshalling, first class is defined and then xml contents are parsed into the class using JAXB. In my case every XML file will have different elements and there is no guarantee which tags will come in which XML file. Also how to have hierarchical Tree structure. Based on my requirement, can you show some example or lay basic structure which i will take it forward. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have a pretty broad question here, so it will be hard to give a definitive answer, but one thing to look at might be un/marshalling `List`s of and abstract base type from which all of your sub-tags will inherit from. Your XML will need to conform to some schema that allows for a structure as you describe, where tags are allowed to be different under a specific root tag, so your classes can be structured accordingly. Otherwise, you will need to have a separate class structure for each combination...

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/30/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/) to see if it helps explain things.

Comment: @RyanJ thanks. I understand your point now clearly. but the problem is there can be any combination at run time and generating separate class from it will not be viable option. Do you recommend any other technique can be used for this requirement. Is there any other way we can parse the file by reading XML and finding the tags at runtime and generating childs in some recursive fashion and creates a tree structure.

Comment: You can do what you want, but you need to make sure that your XML is "valid." A set of XML documents that don't conform to a single XML schema will require a very customized approach, because there will need to be a class that can hold all of the different types that will be found at runtime, and JAXB for example, will need to contain the objects and annotations necessary to tell it what to do with all of the tags it sees. Using `List`s of a generic supertype would be one way to go, but the XML as it's shown here may not support that particular solution, which is why I mention the schema.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is exactly what tree-based models of XML like DOM, JDOM2, and XOM do. These all include a builder program that parses the XML and delivers a tree like the one you describe.